# set innerHTML of div tag under li tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have below the html and I want to add the innerHTML of div tag.

```
<li id="liFlashDetectionMessage" class="width730 height30 divfloatleft marginleft15">
    <div id="divFlashDetectionMessage" class="divfloatleft marginleft5 width730">
    </div>
</li>
```

I have written below but it is giving javascript error.

```
document.getElementById("divFlashDetectionMessage").innerHTML = "Oops, flash player is not installed on your browser.";
```

Can anyone help how to do it?

Comment: what was the error thrown?

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference - This is because javascript is not finding div tag under li tag.

Comment: Looks fine to me

here is the http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/bBSNs/

Comment: Is the <li> being generated based on some condition?

Comment: When is the script being executed? The error indicates that the element is not available to set value,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having seen your full code, I bet your code is run before the DOM is ready.

Since the browser parse your code from top to bottom and execute any JavaScript immediately, if your `<script>` tag is put before the actual `<div>` element you try to manipulate, in your source, then it won't find a match when you run `document.getElementById()` because at the time that piece of code is execute, the browser still doesn't know about the tag you declare further down the page.

Try moving your script-element to the bottom of your page, just before your closing `</body>` tag.

If you can't/don't want to move your JavaScript, then you would have to listen for the DOM-ready event the browser fires as soon as the DOM is ready, and execute the code when you know the DOM is ready.